# How to insert 2 post (submitted) values that begins with specific names to same table row, and loop for more same results?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach, insert

How to loop 2 values from a submitted form that begins with specific names, insert it in a mysql table row and loop for more?

I have a post form with many input select and textareas, in a part of that form there are 2 fields (link, description) then i have a button which generate an extra line with the same fields but adding the number 1 2 3 in the name. So here how it looks like when i click to generate the new line of that 2 fields:

```
<label for="stack_input"><input id="stack_input" name="extravalue" value="" type="text"></label>
<label for="flow_input"><input id="flow_input" name="secondextravalue" value="" type="text"></label>

<label for="stack_input"><input id="stack_input" name="extravalue1" value="" type="text"></label>
<label for="flow_input"><input id="flow_input" name="secondextravalue1" value="" type="text"></label>

<label for="stack_input"><input id="stack_input" name="extravalue2" value="" type="text"></label>
<label for="flow_input"><input id="flow_input" name="secondextravalue2" value="" type="text"></label>
```

Now i post the form together with the rest inputs and textareas of the form, but i want those each 2 extra fields at a time to be added to a new database row, as a pair to be added on same row each time. For now i can make a foreach but i can add only 1 of the 2 fields at a time to a new table row.

Here the code to make this happen for 1 field. I say to php to take all post data that begins with "extravalue" which is the first of the two (pair generated) input fields, and each time that find a post value begins with "extravalue" to be inserted in the table. Because each time i generate a new line of that two input fields have as base name "extravalue" and "secondextravalue" respectively and each time add the number 1 2 3 etc at the end of the name. Here the code:

```
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) 
    {
        if (strpos($key, 'extravalue') === 0) 
    {

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ('','','$value','','','')")or die("ADD Error: ".mysql_error());

    }
    }
```

Now i want to take each pair of the generated input fields and insert in the database in same row.

So i want to do the following:

For each,

```
"extravalue" "secondextravalue"
"extravalue1" "secondextravalue1"
"extravalue2" "secondextravalue2"

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ('','','$value','$value2','','')")or die("ADD Error: ".mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ('','','$value','$value2','','')")or die("ADD Error: ".mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ('','','$value','$value2','','')")or die("ADD Error: ".mysql_error());
```

In short i want to say to php that every time you find values that begin with "extravalue" and "secondextravalue" to insert them in the same table row, and then to loop to continue searching for the next pair of that two values which begins with the same names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it like this, create the fieldnames as an array: name="extravalue[]"

THat will give you all extra values in an array in your $_POST, allowing you to loop through them at ease, and insert them easily too. Add a counter ($i++;) to the loop, so you can also get the second extra value at ease.